# how to start a message transfer from an android device to a pc

Tags: android, instant-messaging

i am trying to build an instant messaging application for my final year project . i have to design a authentication system for my app i.e. i will communicate with my server (my laptop) by providing my mob no. username and email id, my server will send me a code which i need to re enter in-order to get access to my app. But the problem is i am able to figure it out myself but i lack the knowledge to develop such a server communication system . Can anyone suggest me how to proceed ..

I am providing a much clear picture about my idea.

1. The server should get my device ip address while registering and should store it in a db along with my number and other details.
2. Then it should send me a unique number ( its just a customer id ) through sms.
3. This number is then sent by the me to the server where its matched and then an access token is sent for me .

   as of now this is my aim ....  can anyone guide me ?

Comment: What are the restrictions to this project? Can you take advantage of services to do this?

Comment: actually i must not use any 3rd party services to do this .i can use  those provided by google ..

Comment: Could you use something like [Google AppEngine?](https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1) Also, which languages are you comfortable with?

Comment: i am comfortable with java ... i dont exactly understand how this could solve the purpose

Comment: i also like to mention that i am doing my instant messaging application as an embedded client app not like an app that runs on a browser